# MSDN Windows App Tutorial Trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to follow an introductory tutorial on creating your first windows application. It says I should have this code and be able to create a basic window.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <WinDef.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
        _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
        _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
        NULL);

    return 1;
}

hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

// The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
// szWindowClass: the name of the application
// szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
// WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
// CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
// 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
// NULL: the parent of this window
// NULL: this application dows not have a menu bar
// hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
// NULL: not used in this application
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szWindowClass,
    szTitle,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    500, 100,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);

if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
        _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
        _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
        NULL);

    return 1;
}

// The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
// hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
// nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
ShowWindow(hWnd,
    nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

// Main message loop:
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return (int) msg.wParam;


}
```

It tells me that szClassName is undefined, hInst is undefined, and szTile is defined. Am I missing something obvious here? Here is the link to the tutorial if that helps "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx".

Comment: Screw all the `_T` and `TCHAR` stuff, predefine `UNICODE`, and pass wide strings into the winapi functions. All new applications should support Unicode. Also, check out the full code at the bottom and you'll notice you're missing stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Well the error says it all. It looks like in the tutorial, they do this

```
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Win32 Guided Tour Application");
```

As far as the `hInst` not being defined, I'm not sure. Try adding those two lines and see if it works. I think you will find it was just forgetting those two lines.

You should also have a `WndProc` function which you could simply define as so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP just took a second to compile before filling this in with something useful. Of course, the OP is missing a definition altogether, but for a minimal window, just `return DefWindowProc(…);` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
HINSTANCE hInst;
```

before WinMain scope.